# INSERT usando SEQUENCE .NEXTVAL com outro SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

Eu consigo inserir com essa query em ORACLE

```
INSERT INTO CONF_CODE (ID, OPTION_NAME, ISCHECKED) VALUES (SEQ_CONF_CODE.NEXTVAL, 'Producao', 0);
```

Mas eu preciso preencher essa tabela `CONF_CODE` com uma `SELECT` de outra tabela assim:

```
INSERT INTO CONF_CODE (OPTION_NAME, ISCHECKED)
SELECT DISPLAY_NAME, 0 FROM CONF_LABEL_LOCAL
WHERE "TYPE" = 2 ORDER BY ID;
```

Eu não inclui o `ID` na primeira linha mesmo sendo um campo `not-null` pois eu não sei como inserir um SEQUENCE NEXTVAL com o `SELECT` abaixo.

Estou usando o DBeaver pois meu 'PL/SQL Developer' expirou

### Alguma ideia de solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar a sequence no `select` incluir o "ID" no `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO CONF_CODE (ID, OPTION_NAME, ISCHECKED)
SELECT SOMEDASEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, DISPLAY_NAME, 0 
  FROM CONF_LABEL_LOCAL
 WHERE "TYPE" = 2 ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Ele deu um erro na SEQUENCE:  SQL Error [2287] [42000]: ORA-02287: número de sequência não permitido aqui. Eu só tenho as propriedades de seq value:1, increment: 1 val_min: 0 val_max: 99999999. tem ideia do pq?

Comment: estou lendo a documentação onde não se pode usar SEQUENCE em sub-query

Comment: claro que pode, olha esse exemplo que montei agora: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5fe63/1   deve estar fazendo algo errado na query ou usando uma sequence errada

Comment: sim. deu certo. Era a SEQUENCE, refiz ela (coisa boba!)